# contingency table p values using r base, weights and survey

Tags: r, crosstab, chi-squared, weighted, p-value

r Contingency table weighted p values

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/procstat/67528/HTML/default/viewer.htm#procstat_freq_gettingstarted01.htm

A typical political survey contains one variable called WEIGHT. The purpose of this blog is to compare the contingency table weighted p values using base r, the r weights package, and the r survey package using the extremely simple data set from SAS given above.  The base package results are the same as the results in the base packages of SAS and SPSS.  However the weights package and survey package yield results that are similar to each other but quite different from the results of the base package.  I would be interested in having someone explain to me why these results are so different.  It could be coding mistakes on my part or the different assumptions of the other two packages.  I would be interested in suggestions for the best approach for typical data sets from PEW or ANES (American National Election Studies),

First I give the r code from the base package:

```
>attach(tt)
> print(tt)
    sex internship enrollment count
1  boys        yes        yes    35
2  boys         no        yes    14
3 girls        yes        yes    32
4 girls         no        yes    53
5  boys        yes         no    29
6  boys         no         no    27
7 girls        yes         no    10
8 girls         no         no    23
> xx=xtabs(count~internship+enrollment,data=tt)
> print(xx)
          enrollment
internship no yes
       no  50  67
       yes 39  67
> chisq.test(xx,correct=F)
        Pearson's Chi-squared test
data:  xx
X-squared = 0.81894, df = 1, p-value = 0.3655
> chisq.test(xx)
        Pearson's Chi-squared test with Yates' continuity correction
data:  xx
X-squared = 0.58989, df = 1, p-value = 0.4425
```

These results agree with the results from the following code for SAS (see the above reference):

```
proc freq data=SummerSchool order=data;
   tables Internship*Enrollment / chisq;
   weight Count;
run;
```

The results also agree with the results from the following code for SPSS 15 and the SPSS clone, PSPP:

```
WEIGHT BY COUNT.
CROSSTABS TABLES=INTERNSHIP BY ENROLLMENT
/STATISTICS=CHISQ.
```

However, the following code from weights and survey yield different results:

```
> library(weights)
> wtd.chi.sq(internship,enrollment,weight=count)
    Chisq        df   p.value 
0.0293791 1.0000000 0.8639066 
> library(survey)
> tt.d=svydesign(ids = ~1, data =tt,weights =tt$count)
> svychisq(~internship+enrollment,tt.d)
        Pearson's X^2: Rao & Scott adjustment
data:  svychisq(~internship + enrollment, tt.d)
F = 0.023599, ndf = 1, ddf = 7, p-value = 0.8822
```

Note that the p values for base r (.365 and .443 ) are quite different from the results from weights and survey (.864 and .882).  I would be interested in having someone explain to me the reason for the differences and suggest applicability to the type of political data described above.

Answer (score 0):

When you are reporting the weighted chi squared test — with my `weights` package or the `Survey` package — the baseline analysis assumes that you have weights that are proportional to the probability of selection, not the number of cases. This is the normal way survey data is used. You can get the results you want by setting `mean1` to false in the `weights` package.

```
wtd.chi.sq(internship,enrollment,weight=count, mean1=FALSE)

Chisq        df   p.value 
0.8189423 1.0000000 0.3654896
```